# Shuffle cost in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have run various Spark jobs these last months and have done some performance analysis but not really in depth (not as much as I would have liked). I have noticed a drop of the performance added per core  when you add more and more cores, which is to be expected because Spark must have some constant cost (or at least not parallelizable) operations, so the Amdhal's law applies. However, it is not enough to explain what I'm seeing.

I was trying to reason in an abstract way about the cost of shuffling data over the network depending on the number `m` of machines in the cluster. My reasoning is the following :

### Hypothesis

- the total data size in bytes is `D`
- there are `n >= m` partitions
- the data is randomly (in terms of the partitioning function) but equally (same amount `D/m` of data) distributed  before the shuffle
- the partitioning function is perfectly balanced (=> each partition represents `1/n` of the data)
- each machine must end up with the same number of partitions `n/m` on it to optimize the distribution of the data

### Reasoning

Since the data is randomly distributed, each machine contains `1/m` of each partition before the shuffling. Since each machine must have `n/m` partitions on it, this means each machine already has locally (on disk or in memory) the equivalent `n/m^2` partitions that can stay on this node, namely `D/m^2` bytes.  They contain `D/m` bytes in total, so each machine will send `D/m - D/m^2` bytes, which is `(m - 1)/m^2 *D`.

### Conclusion

The cost of the shuffle is a function of the number of machines and for a fixed number of machines, a linear function of the data size :

`(D,m) -> (m - 1)/m^2 * D`

This function is increasing between 1 and 2, and then decreases. Therefore, the cost of a shuffle step will go down as the number of cores increases. Does it make any sense to you ? I would like opinions on this. Note that before my edit my conclusion was the opposite so... I need to be reassured or contradicted.